Configuring self-hosted Bitwarden behind proxy
I am hosting a jekyll webpage example.com on on debian VM. I have successfully redirected all trafic on both 80 and 443 ports to localhost:4000 where the jekyll server is running.
I am trying to configure a Bitwarden vault that will be accessible on bitwarden.example.com. I have already installed it, using docker and docker-compose. I set up nginx configuration but when I try to access my bitwarden.example.com I get a "Welcome to nginx!" page.
Where should I redirect any incoming traffic to bitwarden.example.com, so that the service is accessible?
EDIT: by running docker network inspect docker_default I found that the containers are all connected to the docker_default bridge network, and each container has its own IP address within the subnet 192.168.64.0/20. The bitwarden-web has the IP address 192.168.64.6, so I plugged it in the nginx file, but I still get the same result when trying to access bitwarden.example.com.
Finally, these are my files:
/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0003/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0003/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    root /home/azureuser/www-example/_site;
    index index.html;

    # First location block for proxying
    location /proxy {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Second location block for handling static files and pretty URLs
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /404;  # This ensures that pretty URLs are handled correctly
        error_page 404 /404;
    }
}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

/etc/nginx/sites-available/bitwarden.example.com
server {
   server_name bitwarden.example.com;


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bitwarden.example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bitwarden.example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        # First location block for proxying
        location /proxy {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.64.6:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
server {
    if ($host = bitwarden.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


   listen 80;
   server_name bitwarden.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

./bwdata/config.yml
http_port: #empty

https_port: #empty

curl 192.168.64.6:5000 gives
<!doctype html><html class="theme_light"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=1010"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#175DDC"/><title page-title>Bitwarden Web Vault</title><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon-16x16.png"/><link rel="mask-icon" href="images/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#175DDC"/><link rel="manifest" href="70501c97b33df95adb32.json"/><script defer="defer" src="theme_head.4cb181fc19f2a308ba73.js"></script><link href="app/main.6113610eaf4544914b28.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body class="layout_frontend"><app-root><div class="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center"><div><img class="mb-4 logo logo-themed" alt="Bitwarden"/><p class="text-center"><i class="bwi bwi-spinner bwi-spin bwi-2x text-muted" title="Loading" aria-hidden="true"></i></p></div></div></app-root><script defer="defer" src="app/polyfills.2fbe6d3186140d959b38.js"></script><script defer="defer" src="app/vendor.33acac557b8cce1903ca.js"></script><script defer="defer" src="app/main.f415391cf543e7cede25.js"></script></body></html>

which looks like bitwarden login page
